# How to display uploaded images from Android app in Android app?

Tags: android, image

I have an Android app and I would like my users to be able to upload images to a web server via a PHP script.

Once a user has uploaded an image I would like other users to see uploaded images.

My questions are, all of my graphic assets (logos, icons etc) are in the various formats (HDPI, XHDPI, XXHDPI etc) so that they scale well in different screen sizes/resolutions.

How would I handle uploaded images? They will be of various sizes as they will be produced by cameras with different mega pixels).

Ideally I would like to show a thumbnail of each uploaded picture and clicking on thumbnail shows full size image.

Comment: You could specify the adequate size in the webservice request and have the server resize the image before sending to the phone.

Comment: But how would this handle the different formats? The HDPI, XHDPI etc

Comment: I don't understand your doubt, if the phone when requesting the image injects the size he wants the picture in the request, you don't need to scale it so you don't need to think in hdpi or xhdpi, it's screen size won't change.